# trouble in changing url string

Tags: php, string, url

I'm transmitting values from a page to an other this way:

```
 <a href="page_name.php?<?php echo base64_encode($value_new ?>=
                       <?php echo base64_encode($values_new); ?>">
```

How can I get these values on another page by using `base64_encode`  ?

Here is the URL when I use `base64_encode`:

```
page_name.php?YW1vdW50=MTQ5OQ==YW1=MTQ5OQvdW50
```

Please give me any suggestion if any one has.

Comment: `base64_encode` produces string, containing equal signs among others. Hence it’s not possible to use the value it returns as is in query params. Your code even does not have matched parenthesis. You might want to `urlencode` the value, and do `base64_decode` on the handler page, but at the moment this code is far from being usable.

Comment: Why are you doing base64_encode for the parameter key?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing with wrong syntax, the correct way to do that is below - (if you have two values)

```
<a href="page_name.php?value1=<?php echo base64_encode($value_new1);?>&value2=<?php echo base64_encode($value_new2);?>">Send</a>
```

Now on the other page(page_name.php) get these values as -

```
$value1 = base64_decode($_GET['value1']);
$value2 = base64_decode($_GET['value2']);

echo $value1;
echo $value2;
```

you can also add multiple values by adding - &value3 = (thisvalue).

May this help you

Comment: Oh really? `base64_encode`’d string contains equal signs (aka `=`’s.)

Answer (score 0):

Try by this way

```
<a href="page_name.php?value_new=<?php echo base64_encode($values_new); ?>">
```

And access in another page by using

```
echo base64_decode($_GET['value_new']);
```